# Promise/axios: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: mongodb, axios, loopbackjs

Hi I am usuing loopback as a server-side framework to create my application. Since I am new to loopback4 and typescript in general I need your help.  I am using axios to send emails of subscribers to MailChimp, the thing is that, emails are delivered successfully to MailChimp but they are not saved in Database, and backend throws an error `TypeError: Failed to fetch`.

What do you think may cause the issue?

My code is following.

**MailChimp.ts**

```
const axios = require('axios');

export async function keepSubscribers(email: string) {
  const data = {
    members: [
      {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
        email_address: email,
        status: 'subscribed'
      }
    ]
  }
  const postData = JSON.stringify(data)

  const options = {
    url: 'https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/b0404295b1',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'auth 71634e399a09a918610fd25094e6731c-us20'
    },
    data: postData
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios(options, async (error: object, response: { statusCode: number }) => {
      try {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
          return resolve("Email is successfully added")
        } else {
          return error
        }
      } catch (err) {
        reject("Error")
      }
    })
  })
}
```

**WaitList.Controller.ts**

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/camelcase */
import {
  repository
} from '@loopback/repository';
import {
  post,
  getModelSchemaRef,
  requestBody,
  HttpErrors,
} from '@loopback/rest';
import { Waitlist } from '../models';
import { WaitlistRepository } from '../repositories';
import { validateCredentialsWaitlist } from '../services/validator';
import _ = require('lodash');
//const app = require('loopback-component-mailchimp')
import { keepSubscribers } from '../services/MailChimp'

export class WaitlistControllerController {
  constructor(
    @repository(WaitlistRepository)
    public waitlistRepository: WaitlistRepository,
  ) { }

  @post('/waitlists', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Waitlist model instance',
        content: { 'application/json': { schema: getModelSchemaRef(Waitlist) } },
      },
    },
  })
  async create(
    @requestBody({
      content: {
        'application/json': {
          schema: getModelSchemaRef(Waitlist),
        },
      },
    })
    waitlist: Waitlist,
  ): Promise<Waitlist> {
    const foundUser = await this.waitlistRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        email: waitlist.email,
      },
    });
    if (foundUser) {
      throw new HttpErrors.Forbidden(`Email ${waitlist.email} already exists`);
    }

    await keepSubscribers(waitlist.email)
    validateCredentialsWaitlist(_.pick(waitlist, ['email', 'firstName', 'secondName']));
    return this.waitlistRepository.create(waitlist);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
const axios = require('axios');

export function keepSubscribers(email: string) {
  const data = {
    members: [
      {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
        email_address: email,
        status: 'subscribed'
      }
    ]
  }
  const postData = JSON.stringify(data)

  const options = {
    url: 'https://us20.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/b0404295b1',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'auth 71634e399a09a918610fd25094e6731c-us20'
    },
    data: postData
  }


  axios(options).then(function (response: object) {
    console.log(response);
  })
    .catch(function (error: object) {
      console.log(error);
    });

}
```

And to remove `await` from `keepSubscribers(waitlist.email)` in `waitlist.controller.ts`